# How to call OPCUA Method hosted in an OPCUA Server using Milo Stack?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have an OPCUA Server written in Python, which hosts *Variables*, *Properties* as well as *Methods*. This server runs and works as it should. Reading & Writing of *Variables* & *Properties* as well as calling those *Methods* with arguments have all been tested using another OPCUA Client (written in Python).

However, the final aim is to write a similar OPCUA Client using Java and the milo stack, which should connect to the given server and perform all these Reading & Writing of *Variables* & *Properties* as well as call OPCUA *Methods* with arguments.

Reading & Writing of *Variables* & *Properties* work with the milo api calls but calling OPCUA *Methods* seems to not work somehow.

I have been trying to solve the same using examples on the eclipse/milo [git][1] page. But could not get it working.

Can anyone help with a very basic client code example, written in Java using the milo stack that calls a simple OPCUA Method with input arguments and prints out the output argument from the OPCUA Method?

Note: I am using the Milo 0.3.3 version and not the latest 0.6. Since, the project I am working in uses 0.3.3.

Thanks & Regards,
[1]: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/MethodExample2.java

Answer (score 0):

If you go back in time to the `release/0.3.3` branch there is a method example that you can use: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/release/0.3.3/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/MethodExample.java

The current example you linked will not work unless you update the version of Milo you are using.